# adding list with thumbnail of videos in the side bar

Tags: javascript, css, youtube

I want to add list of video with a thumb nail on a side bar i am using JavaScript and HTML can somebody help!? it can also be of a youtube channel.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide what videos you are wanting.
Play list, Channel uploads, custom list.....
Then you can chose which call to make to get your selected videos.

A list of all the calls and testing pages can be found [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/)

Then once you have all your videos ID's, you can do a call to the `videos` call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos..............
```

In that call you can grab the Name, Author, Thumbnail, duration and more.
Then you can use that info to construct a link with thumbnail.

If you are wanting to play it localy on your own site. Then you will need to use the [JS Player api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).